# coupon collector's problem - not equally likely

Tags: probability

From the equally-likely coupon collector's problem I know that the expected number of cards is $n(1+1/2+\cdots+1/n)$.

Now if I were to extend this problem to unequal probabilities, do I just take the weighted average of each of the terms?

Thanks

Comment: Much more difficult problem, that, because the "state" of the system is no longer just the number of types collected.  The state requires specifying which one of each type was collected.  I don't know a simple answer.  You can google different works on that.  I did and here is hte first thing that came up (likely there are a lot of other links on the topic): http://www.d.umn.edu/math/Technical%20Reports/Technical%20Reports%202007-/TR%202012/dai.pdf

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations

Comment: (1) If this is a practical problem about a specific contest, then simulation is quick and easy. (2) In general, if one coupon is very much less likely than the rest, the expected wait is essentially geometric waiting for the scarce coupon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the vector of probabilities for coupons $1$ to $k$, ${p_1,p_2,...,p_k}$ summing to 1, the expected number of trials to complete a collection is:

$\int_0^{\infty } \left(1-\prod _{j=1}^k \left(1-e^{-p_j t}\right)\right) \, dt$